# Airflow retry is showing wrong number Try 5 out of 4

Tags: python, airflow

I'm seeing an inconsistency in Airflow retries or maybe I'm missing something. Basically, I have `retries` set to 3 in the default argument;

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 3
}
```

and set to `3` in the `PythonOperators`.

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task_1',
    python_callable=task_1_process,
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)

t2 = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id="spark_submit_task",
    conn_id="spark_default",
    java_class="${JAVA_CLASS}",
    application='/path/to/myjar-0.1.jar',
    application_args=["${ARG1}"],
    conf=SPARK_CONF,
    dag=dag)

t3 = PythonOperator(
       task_id='task_3',
       python_callable=task_3_process,
       retries=3,
       dag=dag)
```

Which I assume means the job will be retried 3 times if first run failed which means, I should have:

```
Try 1 out of 4 [up_for_retry]
Try 2 out of 4 [up_for_retry]
Try 3 out of 4 [up_for_retry]
Try 4 out of 4 [failed]
```

But in the emails, I'm receiving:

```
Airflow alert: <TaskInstance: MyJob.spark_submit_task 2018-12-06T00:00:00+00:00 [up_for_retry]> 

Try 2 out of 4
Try 3 out of 4
Try 4 out of 4

Airflow alert: <TaskInstance: Airflow alert: <TaskInstance: MyJob.spark_submit_task 2018-12-06T00:00:00+00:00 [failed]>
Try 5 out of 4
```

that is, 3 retries and 1 more retry after which its marked failed. So what's the logic behind these retries or how is it interpreted, as `Try 5 out of 4` kind of sound illogical?

Comment: I have seen these states before when a task is cleared for rerun. Have you verified that anyone with access to the instance hasn't cleared and rerun the tasks?

Comment: @andscoop I can confirm tasks were not cleared and rerun